# How to wait for an image to appear on a certain application?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am using regions to identify an equal button and i need the application to wait until seeing the equal buttom image, but it pops up an error "Timeout".

Here is the steps that i performed:

1- I took a screenshot of the equal button of a calculator in region mode.

2- I changed the retain image to True in the region editing page.

3- I build a flow to lanuch the application, Then activate the application, then a wait stage to wait for the key= to appear
[image]

But it always pops up an error that timeout!
[image]

And here is the flow
[image]

How to change the flow and make it to wait for the equal region to appear and not to time out ?

Comment: The flow looks fine. I think the way you are spying the image might not be. In such cases, you usually use 'Position: Anywhere' and 'Location Method: Image' in the region editor (BP v6+, in versions prior to v6, it's more complex). Then you have to 'check exists' in the wait stage.

Comment: How long are you waiting for it to appear? And what are the dimensions of your region and image-to-search (ITS)? BP's Image Recognition (IR) loops over each pixel in the region, starting at top-left all the way to bottom-right (minus the dimensions of the ITS). If the pixel matches, BP then starts comparing the 'snippet'  of the region to the ITS. All of this probably with the default 80% certainty interval. Since the calculator only has 4-5 colors, this IR algorithm becomes quite time consuming. Conclusion: Try to set the wait time to a long period to test if this is the case.